# IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f when I switch different pages of view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, illegalstateexception

I create a view pager which has three pages, in which each there is a nested view pager, when I click the third tab and then first tab in outer view pager to come back to first tab, the android program crash, the output pasted as below.

but if I set the offscreenPageLimit attribute to be 2 to include the third tab, then the exception didn't occur any more. Is there anyone can figure out the reason?

Thanks in advance.

> 2022-02-17 16:01:16.076 31179-31179/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.versa.vanilla, PID: 31179
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: unique id 5a90c1da-befc-45b3-8e34-89ec0e757b9c
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:960)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:328)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1461)
> at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:21018)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4000)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4006)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4006)
> at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:20996)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:639)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:3010)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:3001)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:580)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:285)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:311)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:249)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
> at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:3398)
> at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1856)
> at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1849)
> at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1809)
> at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:2249)
> at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:2438)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
> at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28677)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Answer (score 0):

```
viewpager2.setSaveEnabled(false)
```

Maybe this should help prevent the crash

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your xml viewpager2 component.

```
 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_below="@id/tabBar"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:saveEnabled="false" > //this line
```